# Did languages before C/C++ have pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, implementation, pascal

Was there any pointer usage in old languages such as FORTRAN (pre Fortran-90), cobol or pascal?
If not, then what is the method those languages used to implement the works done by pointers that are used in today's high level languages.

> And  As there is no pointers in java
>   is there any way other way to
>   replicate the work done by a pointer.

Comment: pascal did have pointers something like `p^` and you can do everything w/ array and indexes. Could not resist, so an edit: *As all Real Programmers know, the only useful data structure is the Array. Strings, Lists, Structures, Sets -- these are all special cases of arrays and can be treated that way just as easily without messing up your programing language with all sorts of complications. The worst thing about fancy data types is that you have to declare them*

Comment: @bestsss Real programmers don't know about linked lists?

Comment: @Lundin, you can implemented a linked list w/ just an array. Even, Jerry Coffin explain how he has implemented a linked list in fortran.

Comment: @bestsss No you can't. The definition of an array is something you can index with direct access. You can implement a linked list with *a raw chunk of adjacent, statically allocated data*, but you cannot address individual bytes of it through indexing. You will have to go through the list of next pointers. Otherwise it wouldn't be a linked list, as it wouldn't have the ability to add/remove nodes at any location.

Comment: @Lundin, sure you can address the individual bytes/words/chucks, they will be just out of order. Imagine you need contains(xxx) or hash()/sum() you dont have to address the array in a consecutive way to get the proper result. The linked properties would be interesting only (that's the usual case, but still) when you need the data to be ordered. Point is: the array still is useful w/o the ordering index. As for the definition of the array: I guess it'd be too narrow for a RP :)

Comment: @Lundin: I hope you can implement a linked-list with an array, because your entire memory space is exactly that: An array of bytes.

Comment: @bestsss Then it is a hash table, yes?

Comment: @Ben An array is a definition used in programming, for a number of objects allocated adjacently in memory. By definition it can be indexed. Your raw program memory is not directly part of any high level language. The memory map of a CPU may also not contain adjacent items, they may be allocated anywhere in the memory space with illegal addresses in between. Also, physical memory cells/banks typically don't allow objects to be allocated across them. There is also the issue of alignment. And then finally there's the heap where objects may be allocated segmented and then by definition not arrays.

Comment: @Lundin: That's what an "array of T type" in *programming language of your choice* is.  An array is something far more fundamental, a sequence of memory locations addressable by index.  And I have no idea where you came up with "physical memory cells/banks typically don't allow objects to be allocated across them".

Comment: @Ben Try Google for array. And oops I meant to write physical memory circuits.

Comment: @Lundin: You're not helping your case.  On modern systems with multi-channel memory controllers, any object larger than the channel width can be striped across multiple banks (striped for speed).  That uses multiple banks, multiple circuits, multiple whatever.

Answer (score 7):

Algol 68 had references that were a lot like C/C++ pointers.

Pascal had pointers, though you couldn't do arithmetic on them.

PL/I had pointers.

In FORTRAN and COBOL, you mostly lived without such things as dynamic allocation written in the language. I did once write some linked-list code in FORTRAN that used an array, with an array index as the link to the "next" item (i.e., x[1] was a data item, x[2] was its link to the next data item, x[3] was another data item, and so on). Calling that "clumsy" was being almost excessively generous.

Comment: I learned how to use pointers from Pascal.  The fact that I had achieved proficiency in four assembly languages by then might have helped.

Comment: @David, likewise, I learned pointers and OO in pascal, but knowing a few assembler languages does help. Actually I was masterfully surprised by the native pointer arithmetic in C.

Comment: My Data Structures class in college was taught using Fortran 77, and we did the same thing, using arrays to implement list, stack, and tree structures.  Not fun, but that the time none of us wanted to touch C (our program had just switched over from Pascal, and none of the professors or TAs had enough experience with C to teach it properly).

Comment: @John Bode: would the current professors/TAs were so good at recognizing their limitations!

Comment: @Jerry That is an advanced lookup table, not a linked list.

Comment: @Lundin: At the risk of sounding condescending and arrogant, it sounds to me like you simply don't understand what's being discussed.

Comment: @Jerry: How's that "clumsy"?  Take away the strong-typing of the array, increase the array to fill virtual memory, and what you're left with is a "normal" linked list.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: it's not that they were good at recognizing their limitations, it's that we had just suffered through a semester of C being taught by people who didn't know it and didn't want to touch the stuff again.

Comment: @John, too bad, you spoil it x.x

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That's all entirely true, but it was still clumsy to work with.

Comment: @Jerry: I submit a saner way to accomplish the same thing would be `x[1]` is a data item, `x[x[1]]` is the next item, `x[x[x[1]]]` the third item?  I think that's how FAT file systems find cluster chains.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That works for FATs because one sector can only belong to one file. With a normal linked list, it's entirely reasonable for a given value to occur in two (or more) different lists, and/or occur more than once in the same list. Your scheme simply won't work for cases like those.

Answer (score 3):

BCPL had the construct `a*[b]` (which could be simplified to `a!b` in our implementation, a 6809 embedded system compiler running on a 3B2 UNIX box) which was equivalent to `a[b]` in C. Of course, BCPL only had the concept of words, without all the structures and so forth that give C more power.

`a!b` was a word offset from a word address but the implementation we used also had options for byte offset from word address `a!%b`, and byte offset from byte address `a%%b`.

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing BCPL with some other language? according to my copy of Richards' BCPL manual, elements of a vector are accessed via `v*[42]`

Comment: Interesting, @Christoph, the `a!b` must have been an extension for our implementation as well (like the `!%` and `%%`). Since that was the only BCPL I ever used, I thought it was part of the base language. Adjusted answer to reflect this.

Comment: you can find a PDF version of the reference manual for BCPL (and other languages) at http://www.fh-jena.de/~kleine/history/ ; there's another PDF version floating around the net - however, the other version has been OCR-ed, leading to some confusing and sometimes subtle errors (Rvalue <-> Lvalue)

Answer (score 0):

In these languages is possible to pass parameters to functions *by reference* or *by value*. By reference means exactly passing a pointer to that function. This is done in modern languages such as C# and Visual Basic too.

Comment: References don't allow you to do any pointer arithmetics however. A reference is best described as a limited subset of a pointer. And btw, Visual Basic is *not* a modern language.

Comment: @Lundin: This is basically taking C++'s implementation of pointers and references as the definitions of the terms themselves. Pascal pointers don't support arithmetic. References in Algol 68 are much closer to C++ pointers than to C++ references.

Comment: It might just be the definition, since modern languages (ie C# and Java) use references in the same manner as C++.

Comment: @Lundin: No they don't.  C++ references cannot be rebound.  References in C# and Java can.

Comment: Standard/Classic Pascal didn't. Nearly any 32/64-bit production compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget ADA (and VHDL) *access types*.  And assembly and (gasp) machine code support indirection, although there's no *pointer* type, it's all in the usage.

Comment: *And assembly and (gasp) machine code support indirection*, reminds me 6502 where *the pointer* was in the code with absolute indexing since the zero page+Y indirection was limited (due to having very few available bytes)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality represented by pointers has been present in computer machine languages since very early on, so languages have always allowed some sort of access to the functionality, even if not always as generally as with pointers. 
I remember consulting on a port of some K&R C code into Fortran 66. The C code was full of pointers to structures, which didn't map nicely into any feature of Fortran 66.

Say the C code has structures like so:

struct datastruct {
int ival;
float fval;
} data[100];

The Fortran mapping had a common block (not sure I have the formatting right, my Fortran 66 is extremely stale):

COMMON /DATASTRUCT/ IVAL(100), FVAL(100)

A function in C which takes a pointer to a structure doesn't have to know whether the structure came from the array or was malloc'ed or anything:

float func(struct datastruct *sp)
   {
      return sp->ival * sp->fval;
   }

When mapped into Fortran 66, all "structures" were just indexes into the arrays contained in the common block:

```
FUNCTION FUNC(INDEX)
COMMON /DATASTRUCT/ IVAL(100), FVAL(100)
RETURN IVAL(INDEX) * FVAL(INDEX)
```

Not nearly as elegant as pointers, but got the job done on a CDC 7600 back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Lisp, a language invented in the 1950s, had pointers.  In fact, pointers were central to the manaagement of data in Lisp.  "Lisp" was short for "List Processor"  and lists were (are) linked lists in Lisp.  This may be one of the earliest languages to use pointers as a building block.

In most dialects of Lisp, a list element costsists of two items.  One is either a primitive data lelement, like a number, or a pointer to the eldest child of this element.  The second element is a pointer to the next sibling of this element.  Tree or graph structures of arbitrary complexity can be built up from these elements.

The first implementations of lisp all had automatic garbage collection.